# Count the number of inputs in form in php

Tags: php, forms, input, count

I have this html form:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    input 1 :<input type="text" name="same">
    input 2 :<input type="text" name="same">
    input 3 :<input type="text" name="same">
    input 4 :<input type="text" name="same">
    input 5 :<input type="text" name="same">
    input 6 :<input type="text" name="same">
    input 7 :<input type="submit" name="calc" value="calc">
</form>
```

How can I count the number of this inputs with php if they all have the same name?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to send multiple values with the same name you should use them as array (using the `[]` notation):

```
<form action="" method="post">
    input 1 :<input type="text" name="same[]">
    input 2 :<input type="text" name="same[]">
    input 3 :<input type="text" name="same[]">
    input 4 :<input type="text" name="same[]">
    input 5 :<input type="text" name="same[]">
    input 6 :<input type="text" name="same[]">
    input 7 :<input type="submit" name="calc" value="calc">
</form>
```

This way, in php you can use `$_POST['same']`, which is an array, and you can loop over it:

```
foreach ($_POST['same'] as $key => $val) {
    // Do something with the values
}
```

If you only wanna know how many submitted you can `count` the values in the array (`count($_POST['same']`).